# How to Get only numeric value in text file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, get, content-management-system, unsigned-integer

I have a text file sample.txt containing

computer
computer.pc = 1
pc

i want only number 1, where i want to assign that value to a variable

```
$number = Get -content "sample.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the number by using the [Regex Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Example code to do this:

```
$number = ([regex]::Match((Get-content "sample.txt"), "\d+")).Value
```

The pattern `\d+` means to match one or more decimal digits and using the `Match` method will return the first match found.

See [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) for additional information regarding the quantifiers available.